# Tomcat7 not starting with netbeans7

Tags: tomcat, netbeans

I have a very odd problem with netbeans 7. I am working on an application using JSF2.2 and Tomcat7.0.34 server. Uptill now everything was working fine but today when I start tomcat from netbeans IDE it shows in log a successful start up  but keeps on saying starting tomcat in status bar. I can access tomcat from "loclhost:8080" and if I manually start tomcat then go to the IDE and start the service it says port 8080 is already in use.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem when trying to startup a service and another task uses the same port. Make sure you have not installed another Tomcat or any other server that listens on this port (8080).

If in windows issuing the command `netstat -a -b -o` will give you a list of open ports on your pc. Check and fing the port and which program is using it

Comment: thanks for your response,its a weird situation. When i reboot my laptop and hit "localhost:8080" nothing happens. I've also checked with the command you provided, currently nothing is listening to port 8080.
Now i fireup netbeans 7.3.1 and go to services and start up the apache tomcat 7.0.42 which i've registered with NB, output windows appear and start showing the logs. In them the server is successfully started and i can access it via browser on port 8080. But NB does'nt see that and stays stuck on "starting tomcat". After a long while, prompts failed to start server

Comment: Refreshed the windows and installed the latest netbeans --- issue gone.